# Prove that for all $\alpha \in \text{On}\setminus \{1\}$ there exists an arbitrarily large $\beta \in \text{On}$ such that :

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, proof-writing, ordinals

$\alpha^{\beta}= \alpha.\beta$.

In order to do this, it is suggested to prove that for all $\alpha, \beta >2$, $\alpha^{\beta}= \alpha.\beta$ iff $\alpha^{\beta}= \beta$.

Here's my proof of this statement :

If $\alpha^{\beta}= \beta$ then $\alpha.\beta= \alpha.\alpha^{\beta}= \alpha^{1+\beta}$.

Notice that $1+\beta = \beta$ iff $\beta$ is infinite. If $\beta$ was finite ($<\omega$), then $\beta=n>2$ and we would have $\alpha^{1+n}= \alpha.\alpha^n\neq \alpha^{n}$ for all $\alpha>2$. Hence if $\beta$ is infinite and $\alpha^{\beta}= \beta$ then $\alpha.\beta= \alpha.\alpha^{\beta}= \alpha^{\beta}$.

Now, suppose that $\alpha^{\beta}= \alpha.\beta$.

Notice that again if $\beta$ was finite, then $2<\beta=n<\omega$ and we would have $\alpha^n=\alpha.n$ which is false for all $\alpha>2$. Hence $\beta$ is infinite. At this point, we know that $\beta$ is successor or $\beta$ is limit.

If $\beta$ is successor then there exists $\delta$ such that $\beta = \delta +1$. Hence $\alpha^{\beta}=\alpha^{\delta +1}= \alpha.{(\delta+1)}\ge \delta +1$ (order preservation on the left with $\alpha>1$).

If there is some $\alpha$ such that : $\alpha.(\delta+1)=\alpha$ we are done. Otherwise $\beta$ is limit. Let us say that $\beta= \sup_{\gamma<\beta}{\gamma}$.

Hence $\alpha^{\beta}=\sup_{\gamma<\beta}{\alpha^{\gamma}}=\sup_{\gamma<\beta}\gamma$ (induction hypothesis). Finally $\alpha^{\beta}=\beta$ and the statement is again proved.

I do not know if my proof is totally correct. Moreover how to understand "$\beta$ arbitrarily large" in the main statement ? Any hints or improvements for the proof of this property ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "There are arbitrarily large $\beta$s such that..." = "For all $x$ there is some $\beta\ge x$ such that..." = $[\forall x,\exists\beta\ge x,\ldots]$

Comment: I suppose that you want to add the restriction $\alpha>1$ in the question title.

Comment: ... and for the main problem, I'd in fact rather consider for given $\xi$ the supremum of $\xi,\alpha^\xi, \alpha^{\alpha^\xi}, \ldots$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed we must have $\alpha>1$ in the initial statement (because of the definition of exponentiation) ! Thank you for the suggestion, it seems that you took the "epsilon number" for $\beta$, the fixed point of the function $\beta \mapsto \alpha^{\beta}$.